# list index out of range while incrementing within for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, transpose

Just a beginner in Python. I am trying to find the transpose of matrix without using numpy. My code is as shown:

```
import fileinput

order = int(raw_input())
arr_input = [int(num) for num in raw_input().split(' ')]
arr = []
index = 0
for i in range(order):
    for j in range(order):
        arr[j][i] = arr_input[index] 
        print(index, i , j)
        index += 1

print(arr)
```

It says `IndexError: list index out of range`, from my understanding the loop terminates while `index` is incremented to `9` but I am not accessing `arr_input[9]`, then why the error? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the input?  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [how-to-ask] Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: i/p: 3 (newline) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 o/p: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transpose.py", line 13, in <module>
    arr[j][i] = arr_input[index] 
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @seema Please edit your question, if you have additional information. You can't format code in comments and people tend not to read it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens on the first iteration of your loop:

```
arr = []
i = 0
j = 0
arr[i][j] = ...
```

Try it out in the [REPL](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode).

```
>>> arr = []
>>> i = 0
>>> j = 0
>>> arr[i][j] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So what happened?

- `arr[0][0] = 1` means "set the first item of list `arr[0]` to be 1."
- `arr[0]` means "the first item of list `arr`."
- `arr` is an empty list; it does not have a first item. So the expression `arr[0]` for that program state is erroneous.

How do we fix it? We need to make sure we create a list for each row.

```
# Create a blank matrix
for j in range(order):
    arr[j] = []

# Now fill in the values
for i in range(order):
    for j in range(order):
        arr[j][i] = ...
```

Comment: I am not sure REPL is self-explanatory for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your code a bit for it to work properly.

```
import fileinput

order = int(input())
arr_input = [int(num) for num in input().split(' ')]
arr = []
index = 0

for j in range(order):
    arr.append([])

for i in range(order):
    for j in range(order):
        print(index, i , j)
        arr[j].append(arr_input[index])
        index += 1

print(arr)
```

I can explain why you are getting IndexError: list index out of range

```
arr[j][i] = arr_input[index]
```

through this line of code you are trying to access jth row and ith column of the array arr but arr is just an empty array.
so first you have to do this

```
for j in range(order):
        arr.append([])
```

p.s: while assigning values in an empty array always use append() method to avoid "list index out of range error".

Hope this will help you

Comment: appended empty row to jth of array arr, but while assigning arr[j][i] = arr_input[index], its shows the same error.

Comment: After appending empty rows or more simply we can say that you have appended empty lists to arr. Since, those lists are empty, the values have to be appended instead of being assigned. Use   arr[j].append(arr_input[index]) instead of arr[j][i] = arr_input[index]. Please refer my code.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. Thanks ! :D